# Can we say, "the evil" to mean "all the people who are morally bad"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I know we can say "the good" to mean "all the people that are morally good" as you can see [here,](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/good) while "good" without the definite article means, "that which is morally right" or "the force that produces morally right action." I wonder if it is also correct to say "the evil" to mean, "all the people that are morally bad". I know that without the definite article, "evil" means "something that is really bad and harmful" or "the force that produces morally right action." Can we use "evil" wit the definite article to mean, "all the people that are morally bad"? Let me make up some example sentences:

> **The evil never win.** *(Meaning: Evil people never win.)*

> **The evil finally lost the battle.** *(Meaning: Evil people finally lost the battle.)*

> **The evil don't have any conscience.** *(Meaning: Evil people don't have any conscience.)*

I am asking this because I couldn't find the information I needed in dictionaries.

Comment: *we can say "the good" to mean "all the people that are morally good"*. That's "just about" true, but it's not really useful for a non-native speaker. Mostly you *can't* use "the good" like that without it sounding very strange indeed. Same applies to "the damned" (who stereotypically [*don't cry*](https://cinema-fanatic.com/2011/11/21/movie-quote-of-the-day-the-damned-dont-cry-1950-dir-vincent-sherman/)), or "the poor" (who are stereotypically [*always with us*.](https://biblehub.com/matthew/26-11.htm)) Such usages should be restricted to ***poetic*** contexts, for the most part.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+evil+do+not+appear%22) are a couple of written instances of "the evil" used as a "generic" reference to "evil people". It's "valid", but I suggest you should not copy it.